# How to run both of my foreach loops not just one

Tags: php, mysql

I am running these two foreach loops to get data from my database, however I can only get one or the other to work when I need both to do so.

```
if ($stmt->rowcount() > 0) {
        foreach($stmt as $row) {
            $ResultsCounter++;
            $htmlResult .=  "<div style='margin-right:5px; width:280px' class='col-md-4 well text-center'>" .
                                "<h4>". $row['BusinessType'] . "</h4>" 
                            ."</div>";                      
            } 
        } else{
            $htmlResult .= "<h1 class='text-center'>Sorry no search results found please search again</h1>";
    }

    if ($stmt->rowcount() > 0) {
        foreach($stmt as $row) {
            $ResultsCounter++;
            $htmlResult1.=  "<li><a href='#'>" . $row['BusinessType'] . "</a></li>";            
        } 
    }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: you might be able to reset() the iterator cursor between the two loops, allowing you to loop over it once again.

Comment: Why not just add `htmlResult1.=  "<li><a href='#'>"...` into the first loop?

Answer (score 4):

Just do it in one shot :

```
$htmlResult = '';
$htmlResult1 = '';

if ($stmt->rowcount() > 0) {
    foreach($stmt as $row) {
        $ResultsCounter++;
        $htmlResult .=  "<div style='margin-right:5px; width:280px' class='col-md-4 well text-center'>" .
                            "<h4>". $row['BusinessType'] . "</h4>" 
                        ."</div>";   
        $htmlResult1.=  "<li><a href='#'>" . $row['BusinessType'] . "</a></li>";            

    } 
} else{
        $htmlResult .= "<h1 class='text-center'>Sorry no search results found please search again</h1>";
}
```